# CouchDB works slow for the first time

Tags: couchdb

The problem I am facing with couchDB is whenever I hit any database for the first time, it fetches quite slowly, though the speed is increased from the second time. Is there any workaround we can do so that this glitch gets removed for the first time as well?

Comment: 1) are you fetching views or individual documents? 2) if views, which couchdb version do you use? 3) is "slow" 200ms or more like 10-30 seconds?

Comment: 1) We are fetching views 2) Version - 3.1.1 3) "slow" - more than 10 secs

Answer (score 0):

Secondary indexes in CouchDB are not updated during document write operations ([doc](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/main/config/indexbuilds.html)). So the delay is because the view is actually generated for the first time.

For CouchDB 3.x: look into tuning background indexing

For CouchDB 2.x and before: upgrade and/or prefetch your views regularly so they've been built at the moment you need them quickly available

Ah, and if you're doing mango queries, then make sure required indexes are defined in the first place so you're not rescanning the DB every time :)